# order statistics for components of a random unit vector

Tags: pr.probability

Suppose you sample uniformly from the unit vectors in R^n. What are the distributions of the order statistics of the magnitudes of the components of the sampled vectors? That is, for 1 <= i <= n and x in [0,1], what is the probability that the i'th largest component of the vector (in absolute value) is less than or equal to x?

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but would it help to model the uniform distribution on the sphere by a random vector  $(X_1/R, X_2/R, ..., X_n/R)$ where $X_1, \dots, X_N$ are i.i.d. standard Gaussians and R is defined to be $(X_1^2+\dots+X_n^2)^{1/2}$ ? Or have you tried this already?

Answer (score 2):

There has been some work in the physics community on extreme statistics (i.e. distribution of largest and smallest components) of random vectors. See, [link text](http://arxiv.org/abs/0708.0176/) for example. The largest component is approximately distributed like a Gumbel random variable, while the smallest component is approximately distributed like an exponential random variable.

Answer (score 1):

The distribution should be obtainable by integrating over the section of the simplex segment of the surface of the hypersphere bounded by the points (1,0,0,0,...), (1,1,0,0,0...)/sqrt(2), (1,1,1,0,0...)/sqrt(3) etc. along the ith axis.

All the distributions (n,m) have support contained within the unit interval, are piecewise smooth and share the same set of non-smooth points at the reciprocals of the square roots of the natural numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is closely related to order statistics for normal random variables, so you may find this paper useful: [Percentage Points and Modes of Order Statistics from the Normal Distribution](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-32/issue-3/Percentage-Points-and-Modes-of-Order-Statistics-from-the-Normal/10.1214/aoms/1177704982.full) by Shanti S. Gupta